# ZFS Add a Hdd to raidz-2

Tags: raid, zfs

I have a zfs raidz-2 (raid-6) with 7 4TB hard drives. When I added another hard disk with `zpool add`, it was not included in the original raid ([zpool status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R2E9.png)). Can this still be fixed? Or do I have to create a backup and recreate the pool? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be fixed, that's the way ZFS works. This is a classic newbie mistake: you can't extend a vdev. Worse, if the newly added drive fails, it will fail the whole zpool, including the perfectly sane RAID-Z2 vdev, and you'll lose all of the zpool data!

For a complete list of common ZFS pitfalls, see [this very detailed blog post.](http://nex7.blogspot.com/2013/03/readme1st.html)

Comment: It's a classic "we never finished ZFS so it's still as broken as on day 1" mistake.
The very idea that something as old as ZFS would still have that behaviour after so many users and so many "newbie mistakes" is shocking.
I wonder how much more of ZFS is ill-designed and chalked up to "newbie mistakes".

* by the way it can be fixed, it's just not something you can do with simple zfs commands. When you do add a drive, nothing changes except the zfs config, no damage is done, and the old pool could still be recovered if you know what you're doing. I personally moved to another NAS.

Comment: @Morg. actually there is some progress : https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/12225 . The feature "zpool attach" is out of alpha... Don't know when it will become available though.